# Chainlink VRFV2 fulfillRandomWords() not being called after requestRandomWords()

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, hardhat, chainlink

Hi I want to get a random number using Chainlink **VRFConsumerBaseV2** but the `fulfillRandomWords()` isn't being called after calling `VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.requestRandomWords()`. I can confirm that as "fulfill" is being logged on the console.

**Imp:** I'm testing the contracts (including the Chainlink contracts) **locally** on hardhat. I have added a file `test/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol` which simply imports the VRFV2 Mock contract:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol";
```

Below is my `NFT.sol` file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol';

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721, Ownable, VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestId, uint256[] randomWords);

    struct NFTData {
        uint256 mintedOn;
        uint256 initialPower;
    }

    struct NFTInfo {
        uint256 cardId;
        address userAddress;
        uint256 initialPower;
    }

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface public coordinator;
    uint64 private _subscriptionId;
    bytes32 public keyHash;
    uint32 public callbackGasLimit = 100000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 numWords = 1;

    mapping(uint256 => NFTInfo) private _requestIdToNFTInfo;
    mapping(uint256 => NFTData) private _nfts;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address _coordinator, uint64 subscriptionId, bytes32 _keyHash)
        ERC721(_name, _symbol)
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(_coordinator)
    {
        coordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(_coordinator);
        _subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        keyHash = _keyHash;
    }

    function mintNFT(uint256 cardId, address userAddress, uint256 _initialPower) external onlyOwner returns(uint256) {
        console.log("requestRandom: ");
        uint256 requestId = coordinator.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            _subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
        _requestIdToNFTInfo[requestId] = NFTInfo(cardId, userAddress, _initialPower);
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        console.log("Emit");
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] memory _randomWords) internal override {
        console.log("fulfill");
        NFTInfo memory requestNFTInfo = _requestIdToNFTInfo[_requestId];
        require(requestNFTInfo.userAddress != address(0), "Request not found");

        _safeMint(requestNFTInfo.userAddress, requestNFTInfo.cardId);
        console.log("_safeMint");

        _nfts[requestNFTInfo.cardId] = NFTData(block.timestamp, requestNFTInfo.initialPower);
        emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, _randomWords);
    }
}
```

Below is my `nft.test.js` file:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Contract deployment", () => {
  let nft, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock, owner;

  before(async () => {
    nftFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractFactory("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock");
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.deploy(0, 0);
    await hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock.deployed();

    await hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    await hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(1, 100000);

    nft = await nftFactory.deploy("NFT", "NFT", hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address, 1, "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15");
    await nft.deployed();
  });
  
  describe("NFT", () => {
    it("Mint NFT", async () => {
      await hardhatVrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(1, nft.address);
      await nft.mintNFT(1, owner.address, 100);
      // here "fulfill" isn't being logged
    });
  });
});
```

Is it even possible to test the VRF locally on hardhat or am I missing something?
Any help is highly appreciated. Also any suggestions on correctly testing my NFT contract locally with the VRF are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test this locally unless you create an Oracle application.

The way VFR works is you request randomness to the VFR contract. Chainlink have a separate service running somewhere (not on a blockchain) which monitors the request randomness requests. Chainlink then submits a transaction to the blockchain which calls your fulfillRandomWords function.